# How to store permissions list in Rails session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing Role Permissions system in rails, i want store permissions of user to save number of database query. I use @permissions in ApplicationController but it always get permissions on database each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it in session check here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session

```
session[:permissions] = 'your value'
```

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there." => Users will have some idea what it is because "If you want to save it in session check here" and "accessing-the-session".